# Stripe Checkout is not defined reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to put Stripe into my web page to accept payments. But whenever I load the page I get an error saying that stripeCheckout is not defined. I know this has to do with the library imported in one of my script tags, but I am not sure why it is showing up as undefined. The library imported I thought was correct. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">





    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <title>Store</title>

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" defer></script>
<script>
    var stripePublicKey = '<%= stripePublicKey %>'
</script>
<script src="store.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

and this in my store.js file

```
const stripeHandler = stripeCheckout.configure({
    key: stripePublicKey,
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token){

    }
})

// Removes cart items after they are purchased
const purchaseItems = () => {
    // let cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    // while(cartItems.hasChildNodes()){
    //     cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    // }
    // updateCartTotal()

    let priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0]
    let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', '')) * 100
    stripeHandler.open({
        amount: price
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that that particular Stripe checkout API (and script) is now deprecated.

Here's a link to the docs for the new APIs: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration#client-products

Example from docs:

```js
// client.html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
<button id="checkout-button">Pay</button>

// client.js
var stripe = Stripe('YOUR_API_KEY');

var checkoutButton = document.querySelector('#checkout-button');
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    items: [{
      // Define the product and SKU in the Dashboard first, and use the SKU
      // ID in your client-side code.
      sku: 'sku_123',
      quantity: 1
    }],
    successUrl: 'https://www.example.com/success',
    cancelUrl: 'https://www.example.com/cancel'
  });
});
```

Comment: I am a little confused on how to implement it my code. I changed the script tag to <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script> but it still says that my stripeCheckout is undefined

Comment: Based on the new Stripe APIs, the global variable is called `Stripe`, and not `stripeCheckout`. If you look at the example above, you should be able to follow it and trigger a Stripe redirect to checkout (after you include your API key).